# How to calculate how much percentage I have worked on each project throughout the year in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a Excel spreadsheet with two columns. One shows the total amount I have worked on each project in hours:minutes and next to this in the second column this shows the project.

I need a formula to show how much percentage was spent since 01/01/2013 to now. So basically over 9 months what is the percentage spent on each project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have 50 projects, and the time spent is shown in column A. Drag this down all rows:

```
=A1/sum(A$1:A$50)*100
```